# How to store same JS function with different parameters in array and call them?

Tags: javascript

I need to use a function like this for multiple times with different ids based on different conditions (e.g. select values). I don't want to write a different function for every id because there will be lots of them in the future.

```
var getValue = function(id){

    var Element = document.getElementById(id);

    if(Element){
        if(Element.value){
            return " " + Element.value;
        }
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}
```

I have an array including some other functions:

```
FunctionList = [ SomeFunction, SomeFunction2 ];
```

Based on some conditions, I add `getValue` function with different parameters to this array.

```
FunctionList.push(getValue(SomeId1));
FunctionList.push(getValue(SomeId2));
FunctionList.push(getValue(SomeOtherId));
```

In the end, I need to add outputs of my functions (which are strings) to another string.

```
var updateCode = function(){
    var code = CodeHeader;
    for (var i=0; i<FunctionList.length; i++){
        code += FunctionList[i]();
    } 
    return code;
}
```

But I am unable to use it like this since some items of array are not function names now.
I like pure js solutions, but if it's not possible I can go for jQuery or so.

Comment: Or you can use IIFEs with private members set in constructor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235273/iife-methods-leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind` to create such a tailored function on the fly:

```
FunctionList.push(getValue.bind(null, SomeId1));
```

The first argument (`null` here) will act as `this` during function execution.

This differs from what you had:

```
FunctionList.push(getValue(SomeId1));
```

...as here you don't push a function, but the *result* of a function *execution*. `bind` however, will not execute the function, but create a new one from the given function.

## Alternative

In your example you call the *same* function with *different* arguments. If that is always the case, you could also go for an array of only arguments:

```
argumentList.push(SomeId1); // Not the function, just the argument
// ...etc
```

And then `updateCode` would become:

```
var updateCode = function(){
    var code = CodeHeader;
    for (var i=0; i<argumentList.length; i++){
        code += getValue(argumentList[i]);
    } 
    return code;
}
```

... or shorter by using `map`:

```
var updateCode = () => CodeHeader + argumentList.map(getValue).join("");
```

As in your `getValue` function, you prefix the returned value with a space, you could omit that prefix, and just use `.join(" ")` in the above one-liner. The downside is that it would not deal the same way with empty return values.